# How to tell if pasted data was copied from my page?

Tags: javascript, html, events, contenteditable, paste

I'm trying to write a wysiwyg editor. I don't want people to be able to paste in foriegn html, so I figured I could convert it to text. But I still want the html to be pasted if it originated from the same element (or across the site if possible).

So is there a way to detect from a paste event where the content came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detect the copy event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event).

Use the [setData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData) to include a custom data type e.g. text/whatever. This can include pretty much anything, like where the user copied from, when, etc. You can even upload your own custom data representation in there.

When pasting, grab the corresponding event and look for your custom data type.

Edit: My bad, didn't read carefully about having to preventDefault.

```
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {

    event.clipboardData.setData('text/test', 'sum text here');
    const selection = document.getSelection();

    // Essentially brute force copying selection.
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(range.cloneContents());
    const copy = div.innerHTML;

    event.clipboardData.setData('text/html', copy);
    event.preventDefault();
});

document.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
    const clipboard = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData);
    let pasteTest = clipboard.getData('text/test');
    let paste = clipboard.getData('text/html');
    console.log (paste, '@@@@@@@@@@@', pasteTest);
});
```

Comment: The data that I set with setData() seems to only work if I preventDefault() the copy event (seems like the default behavior overwrites the data I set). But then it doesn't copy the text/html to the clipboard. I would set it manually if I could, but the getData() function doesn't seem to work on copy events, just paste.

Comment: @stackers Sorry, i didn't notice the caveat with preventDefault. I've actually been working with the browser plugins, which are slightly less restrictive.

P.S. strange, it was working a moment ago but i need to run.

Comment: @stackers done, fixed it. It should work on most modern browsers, but do test.

Comment: Beware though IE only supports  `text` (yes not even the standard `text/plain`...) and will throw an Exception if you try to use anything else.

Comment: That does the trick. I was trying to do something similar but ran into the issue of the selection not including html, so putting into a new div first was a good idea. I'm fine with not supporting IE =]

Answer (score 0):

In the copy event of your editor you should add something (unique sign) into it just like a special wrap, so when in paste event you just need to judge whether the data is from your editor according to your sign.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var let_paste = false;

    function handleCopy (e) {

        var clipboardData, pastedData;

        pastedData = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');

        // When let_paste is true the content have been copied from this site
        let_paste = true;

        alert('let it paste!')
    }

    document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener('copy', handleCopy);
```

```html
<div id='myDiv' contenteditable='true'>Copy</div>
```

Consider this code above - my idea is that you set a global variable that control if the content has been copied from this site or not - make an event to set it to true when the content is copied from your site. Then, save the content itself in a variable and compare with the pasted content when the user do the "paste" event.

Comment: What if they copy from your site, then go copy from another site?  When would you reset let_paste back to false?